change the color of the canvas object and return to the original color (2 colors)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>HTML5 Canvas</h1>

<canvas id="myCanvas" onclick="myFunction()" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas3" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas4" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>

<script>
const myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 150, 100);
</script>

<script>
const myCanvas2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
const ctx2 = myCanvas2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
ctx2.fillRect(50, 50, 150, 100);
</script>

<script>
const myCanvas3 = document.getElementById("myCanvas3");
const ctx3 = myCanvas3.getContext("2d");
ctx3.fillStyle = "red";
ctx3.fillRect(50, 50, 150, 100);
</script>

<script>
const myCanvas4 = document.getElementById("myCanvas4");
const ctx4 = myCanvas4.getContext("2d");
ctx4.fillStyle = "red";
ctx4.fillRect(50, 50, 150, 100);
</script>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  const change = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  const ctx = change.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 150, 100);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

there are 4 squares filled with red. need to do to. so that when you click on a square, it changes color to green, and then it changes back to red, and so an infinite cycle.
tried to use "if" in a block of code with a function, with a color change.

You can use a while loop to infinitely switch between green and red, though this is extremely intensive and laggy, so instead there is a for loop commented that you can uncomment and edit to get this to work, but for now this will just quickly switch to green, then to red:
(a sleep function will be useful to delay changing color, also this can be carried out infinitely as long as you can keep clicking)
<script>
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
function myFunction() {
  const change = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  const ctx = change.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 150, 100);
  //for(let i = 0;i < 10000;i++) {
  sleep(2000).then(() => {ctx.fillStyle = "red"; ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 150, 100);});
    //sleep(2000).then(() => {ctx.fillStyle = "green"; ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 150, 100);});
  //}
}
</script>



--Alternatively (this is smoother than my javascript example)--
You can try to use requestAnimationFrame() or use another form of animation to animate the object on click.
Here I used keyframes on a div in css to change it's color when hovered.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div></div>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
 
}
div:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: colorchange 5s;
}

@keyframes colorchange {
  0%   { background: red;}
  50% {background: green;}
  100% {background: red;}
}
</style>
</html>

